# How to use SQL to remove superfluous characters from names?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I remove all superfluous full-stop `.` and semi-colon `;` characters from end of last name field values in SQL?

Comment: The application should clean the data before sending it to the database for storage; the database could have a trigger on the data to reject the characters, but it shouldn't normally clean the data itself (IMO).

Comment: What if the data are already in the database? Then knowing how to clean the data through a SQL query is helpful.

Comment: There is data already in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Substring rows that have a semi-colon or dot :

```
update emp
   set ename = substring(ename, 1, char_length(ename) - 1)
   where ename REGEXP '[.;]$';
```

Comment: I think `ename REGEXP '[.;]$'` would suffice.

Comment: NOTE: Use `CHAR_LENGTH()` instead of `LENGTH()` function.  The `LENGTH()` function returns a number of *bytes*. That's fine for *single byte charactersets* (such as latin1), where the number of bytes is equal to the number of characters. For *multibyte charactersets* (such as utf8), the number of bytes can *differ* from the number of characters. The `CHAR_LENGTH` function returns the number of *characters* for both singlebyte and multibyte charactersets,which is what we want if we're using the number of characters as part of an argument to the  `SUBSTRING()` function.

Comment: Thank you Spencer, I update my answer with char_length()

Answer (score 0):

One way to check of the last character is a "full stop" or "semicolon" is to use a substring function to get the last character, and compare that to the characters you are looking for. (There are several ways to do this, for example, using `LIKE` or `REGEXP` operator.

If that last character matches, then lop off that last character. One way to do that is to use a substring function. (Use the `CHAR_LENGTH` function to return the number of characters in the string.)

For example, something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable t
   SET t.last_name = SUBSTR(t.last_name,1,CHAR_LENGTH(t.last_name)-1)
 WHERE SUBSTRING(t.last_name,CHAR_LENGTH(t.last_name),1) IN ('.',';')
```

But, I'd strongly recommend that you *test* those expressions using a `SELECT` statement, before running an `UPDATE` statement.

```
SELECT t.last_name                                      AS old_val
     , SUBSTR(t.last_name,1,CHAR_LENGTH(t.last_name)-1) AS new_val
 FROM mytable t
WHERE SUBSTRING(t.last_name,CHAR_LENGTH(t.last_name),1) IN ('.',';')
```

Comment: Reviewing my answer, I notice that used `SUBSTR()` and `SUBSTRING()` functions in the example queries. Those two function names are synonyms in MySQL... there's no difference between them. (The query I provided is just one example; there are lots of other queries that will accomplish the same thing.)